# Deprecation : Encoding Utils in org,apache.http.util.EncodingUtils

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic to build android app. After executing command : `ionic build android`. I get 9 warnings related to Deprecation. I have attached a screen shot of the generated warnings. I am new to android and ionic so can any one please help me to solve this?

[image]